# puppet: execution ordering of classes 'instances'

Tags: debian, puppet

I know how I can use resource ordering in Puppet to order built-in types (user, group, cron...) or classes, but I wonder how I can make it for specific instances of classes.

For example, I use puppetlabs/apt module and the apt::source defined type to push wheezy/updates/... apt sources. My code looks like

```
apt::source { 'debian_wheezy':
    location        => 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/',
    release         => 'wheezy',
    repos           => 'main contrib non-free',
    include_src     => false,
}
apt::source { 'debian_wheezy_updates':
    location        => 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/',
    release         => 'wheezy-updates',
    repos           => 'main contrib non-free',
    include_src     => false,
}
```

I want to make use of another module to configure HAProxy, but I need to define another apt::source to configure wheezy backports because haproxy is not available on the standard wheezy repository. So I want to indicate that my haproxy class depends of my apt::source type defining wheezy backports.

I have tried something naive like

```
Class['apt::source'] -> Class['haproxy']
```

but logically this does not make sense: I want to specify one specific instance of apt::source.

Do anybody knows how I can do that?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare the haproxy class you can require it, e.g.:

```
class { 'haproxy':
  require => Apt::Source['debian_wheezy'],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works if my apt::source declaration is in my node file, but can't find how to do it if it's in a separate file (a 'profile' named profiles::apt::wheezy_backports). Any idea?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If you declare `apt::source { 'whatever'` you can require it via `require => Apt::Source['whatever'],`

Comment: in fact... it works! Must have been a typo or something. thks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the relevant `apt::source` resource in it's own class. Example:

**myapt:**

```
require myapt::default
require myapt::backports
```

**myapt::default:**

```
apt::source { 'debian_wheezy':
    location        => 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/',
    release         => 'wheezy',
    repos           => 'main contrib non-free',
    include_src     => false,
}
apt::source { 'debian_wheezy_updates':
    location        => 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/',
    release         => 'wheezy-updates',
    repos           => 'main contrib non-free',
    include_src     => false,
}
```

**myapt::backports:**

```
apt::source { 'debian_wheezy_backports':
    location        => 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/',
    release         => 'wheezy-backports',
    repos           => 'main contrib non-free',
    include_src     => false,
}
```

**myhaproxy:**

```
require myapt::backports
class { 'haproxy': }
```

Comment: I thought about creating a 'wrapper' class, but I prefer to find another solution.